If the `Free pointer` is stored at `0x40` what do the rest of `0x41` to `0x5f` do?
Layout in Memory
Solidity reserves four 32-byte slots, with specific byte ranges (inclusive of endpoints) being used as follows:

0x00 - 0x3f (64 bytes): scratch space for hashing methods

0x40 - 0x5f (32 bytes): currently allocated memory size (aka. free memory pointer)

0x60 - 0x7f (32 bytes): zero slot

Scratch space can be used between statements (i.e. within inline assembly). The zero slot is used as initial value for dynamic memory arrays and should never be written to (the free memory pointer points to 0x80 initially).

Solidity always places new objects at the free memory pointer and memory is never freed (this might change in the future).

Elements in memory arrays in Solidity always occupy multiples of 32 bytes (this is even true for bytes1[], but not for bytes and string). Multi-dimensional memory arrays are pointers to memory arrays. The length of a dynamic array is stored at the first slot of the array and followed by the array elements.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_memory.html#layout-in-memory
As per my understanding a free memory pointer points to the last address location where memory is stored . Free memory pointer is always at 0x40 . Then what is the rest of 0x41 - 0x5f for ?
The docs just say 0x40 - 0x5f (32 bytes): currently allocated memory size (aka. free memory pointer)   without explaining much .

When you allocate 1 byte of memory, that 1 byte of data is stored at 0x40 and the free memory pointer will now point to 0x41.
When you allocate another 1 byte, that 1 byte of data gets stored at 0x41 and the free memory pointer will now point to 0x42.  And so forth.
Gas constraints will prevent you from allocating so much memory.
Some related references:

What is the maximum size of memory in solidity?

Why does Solidity never free memory?


